# JQuery onclick execute event of input field

Tags: jquery, input

I don´t know if it´s possible do this ,  in this case i want when click over input text field activate function in jQuery and after of this action execute the code of jQuery - inside onclick - , i put my example :

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="" class="input_text_register" id="pass" onclick="jQuery("#list").show();"/>
```

I can´t do this works , i supose i have some error because no get works finally , in this case the activation from input text field open other div for show informations

Thank´s , Regards !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#pass').click(function () {
    $("#list").show();
});
```

or

change `onclick="jQuery("#list").show();"`

to

`onclick="jQuery('#list').show();"`

Answer (score 3):

Try like

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="" class="input_text_register" id="pass" onclick="myfun();"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function my_fun() {
         jQuery("#list").show();
     }
</script>
```

Or you can also do like

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="" class="input_text_register" id="pass"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#pass').on('click',function(){
             jQuery("#list").show(); 
         });
     });
</script>
```

Or even simply you can try like

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="" class="input_text_register" id="pass" 
onclick="jQuery('#list').show();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you included `jQuery` library?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Better give it as explicit.

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="" class="input_text_register" id="pass" onclick="clickIt();"/>
<script">
     function clickIt() {
         jQuery("#list").show();
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either try escaping your quotes like this:

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="" class="input_text_register" id="pass" onclick="jQuery(\"#list\").show();"/>
```

or change them

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="" class="input_text_register" id="pass" onclick="jQuery('#list').show();"/>
```